# ease-in & ease-out animation is not working for search bar

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I made search button to show and hide search bar on the navigation bar with ease in and ease out but the animation is not working and it doesn't give me error in the console. I will not write the whole html code, this is the sample code of html.

```js
$('.search-icon a').on("click", function(){
    $('body').addClass('show-search').children('.search-box-outer').slideDown();
    return false;
});

$('.close-search').click(function(){
    $('.search-box-outer').removeClass('show-search').slideUp();
    return false;
});
```

```css
.search-box-outer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 99999999;
  left: 0;
  top: -60px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.search-box {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 60px;
}

.search-box .form-control,
.search-box .form-control:focus {
  height: 82px;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.close-search {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  width: 60px;
  height: 82px;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 82px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.show-search .search-box-outer {
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
  width: 100%;
}

.search-box-outer .container {
  padding: 40;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="home">home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="aboutus">aboutus</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contactus">contactus</a>
      </li>
      <li class="search-icon">
        <a href="#!">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="search-box-outer">
  <div class="search-box">
    <form>
      <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Type &amp; Hit Enter to Search" />
    </form>
    <a href="#!" class="close-search">
      <i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the problem? Other than css problems (*your input is not completely hidden on top, and your close button is out of window bounds*), it seems to be working. Input comes down when I click search and goes up when I click close.

Comment: @Ozan ease-in and out is not working any ideas ???

Comment: you can use toogleClass like this $('.search-icon a').click(function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('show-search');
});. But you still have to fix the css

Comment: i don't see any problem with my css ???

Comment: @AmrAshraf seems to be working..you want a fade in and out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the position to absolute in the class search-box-outer, and in class show-search search-box-outer, and added display: none, and it worked

**jquery**

```
$('.search-icon a').on("click", function(){
        $('body').addClass('show-search').children('.search-box-outer').slideDown();
        return false;
    });

    $('.close-search').click(function(){
        $('.search-box-outer').removeClass('show-search').slideUp();
        return false;
    });
```

**css**

```
.search-box-outer{
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%; 
    height:60px; 
    float:left; 
    background:#fff; 
    z-index:99999999; 
    left:0;
    top:-60px;
    display: none!important;
}


.show-search .search-box-outer{
    top:0;
    position: absolute!important;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 100%;
}
```